# Translating Delphi collection to C++ Builder code (TIdPOP3)

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy

Can someone help me translate a line from this code to C++ Builder:

http://blog.onkeysoft.com/2011/04/20/how-to-prepare-a-connection-to-pop3-server-with-indy-tidpop3/

I was doing good until this line:

```
 POP3Client.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := tidsasl(con_sasl_anonymous);
```

Additional question - is there a "good" order of SASL mechanisms to try out - from most secure to least secure? In other words, what would be a good order of them? I would try with SHA1 first, then MD5 then... something here... and PlainText as last one.

Comment: `POP3Client>SASLMechanisms>Add>SASL = (TIdSASL*)con_sasl_anonymous;`

Comment: That doesn't work because Add(TIdSASListEntry *) is a function - it expects `TIdSASListEntry *` as parameter so there may be something wrong with above code?

Comment: Is `Add` really a method with parameter ? I don't know, just looking at the [`Add`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TCollection.Add) method of `TCollection` class, it doesn't expect any parameter (maybe Indy has the `TIdSASLEntries` based on a different class, I don't know). Anyway, that code is unsafe since adding of that collection item may fail and you may access not existing object. Safer is to have a variable where you'll store the added collection item. It might be [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/hz4NLap2).

Comment: Yes, you are right... `(TIdSASLListEntry*)` is return parameter from `Add()` function which doesn't require parameters! Can't believe I didn't notice that. Now everything works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future googlers - thanks to TLama:

```
TIdSASLListEntry *se = POP3Client->SASLMechanisms->Add();
se->SASL = (TIdSASL*)con_sasl_anonymous;
```

Or if you prefer C++ style casts:

```
TIdSASLListEntry *se = POP3Client->SASLMechanisms->Add();
se->SASL = static_cast<TIdSASL*>(con_sasl_anonymous);
```

Comment: Assuming `con_sasl_anonymous` is a `TIdSASLAnonymous` component, then you don't need the type-cast at all (the original DElphi code did not need to type-cast, either): `se->SASL = con_sasl_anonymous;`